# Communication between components in Ember

Tags: javascript, ember.js, file-upload, progress-bar

I have a template with two components, a file upload component, and a progress bar to show the upload progress.

```
{{file-upload}}
{{ember-progress-bar progress=progress}}
```

And am using ember-uploader. I'm trying to set the progress of the progress bar like so:

```
uploader.on('progress', e => {
    // send progress to other component
});
```

I've read that you should use actions to communicate between components, but I only have access to that progress value within the filesDidChange function in the upload component, so I don't think I can send it in an action. What is the best way to send this progress value into the progress bar component?

Comment: did not the answer help you at all? I can help further if you leave comments regarding the answer?

Comment: I haven't had a chance to check it out yet, thanks so much for your help. I'll get back to you after I've tested it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is where I use contextual components to enable inter-component communication for components that do not have parent-child relation (one does not render the other within its template).

Please take a look at the following [twiddle](https://ember-twiddle.com/f09acdbcbcc309ae43426b7bfdde95c9?openFiles=templates.components.ember-progress-bar.hbs%2Ctemplates.components.ember-progress-bar.hbs) I have prepared for you to illustrate what I mean. I have created mock `ember-progress-bar` and `file-upload` components. Instead of the `filesDidChange` function of course I used `click` function for the mock `file-upload` component and I decided to send `screenX` and `screenY` values to the mouse click event to `ember-progress-bar` component as the progress.

`ember-progress-bar` is used as a contextual component within `application.hbs`; where `ember-progress-bar` yields the `progressUpdated` action with `{{yield (hash progressUpdated=(action 'progressUpdated'))}}` inside its template. Within `application.hbs` (where `ember-progress-bar` is used in block form); this yielded action is retrieved and passed as the `onclick` action to the `file-upload` component.

I do not know if this will help you at all; but this is the technique I heavily use for inter-component communication. I rely on actions yet again thanks to the contextual components (yielding from component and using the component in block form where it is going to be used).

Comment: This didn't end up being a solution for my particular problem as the API server we're using turned out not to be able to provide a partial progress value, but I think it would have worked if it did. Thanks!